# $auth object is empty eventhough my nuxt app is logged in

Tags: authentication, jwt, nuxt.js, token, auth0

I'm very new to both nuxt and auth0. I'm using auth0 with my nuxt app and I have written a piece of code in my main pages mounted hook that enables me to login to the server when I use `$auth.login()` then it returns me to my app and gives me a token in the url. I can get my user profile's info using the token with `/auth/me` in my mounted hook but when I log `$auth.$state` it says you're not logged in:

```
loggedIn: false
strategy: "auth0"
user: null
```

How can I use `$auth` object with my `auth0` code?
This is my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/', 
      callback: '/auth/signed-in'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: false,
      auth0: {
        domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        client_id: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      }
    }
  },
```